Examples of Concentration inequalities
I'm looking for relations of the form
$$
P[X\leq \mu_N-\delta_{N,n,\epsilon}]\geq \epsilon
$$
where the random variable $X$ is the fraction of successes in $n$ samples from a binary population of size $N$, $\mu_N$ is the fraction of successes in the total population and $\delta_{N.n.\epsilon}$ is a deviation term.
I'm aware that Serfling inequality is an example of the following relation.
$$
P[X\leq \mu_N-\delta_{N,n,\epsilon}]\leq \epsilon
$$
I'm looking for an example where I get a lower bound on the probability instead of an upper bound.
